# Запрос php mysqli c формированием переменной

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть код:

```
$x[status][vip]     = 2;
$x[status][standard] = 1;

"SELECT 
@status_:= status AS status_, 
$x[status][@status_] AS level
FROM users"
```

В таблице `users` поле `status` имеет значение vip, соответственно level должен = 2, но в результате получаю ошибку по выше приведенному запросу.

Вопрос, возможно ли как то сформировать переменную `$x[status][@status_]` без ошибки?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, откуда Вы берёте значения в $x['status'] (и всегда ставьте кавычки в строковых значениях). Так будет проще избавить Вас от страданий.

Comment: Строки сперва обрабатываются php, а потом уже сформированный запрос отправляется в mysql, у вас в строке есть переменная php $x[status][@status_], вместо неё php должен подставить значение, но он ничего не знает про @status_, соответственно это не будет работать

Comment: Значения в $x[status] указываются перед запросом, в базе значений статусов не держаться только сам статус, не хочется делать много IF()  в запросе что бы присвоить значения.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы прописываете $['status'] в коде (а не берёте его из базы), то лучше всего будет просто сделать вот так:

```
SELECT
    `status` as `status_`,
    CASE `status`
        WHEN 'vip' THEN 2;
        WHEN 'standard' THEN 1;
    END as `level`
FROM `users`
```

Если $x['status'] берётся вдруг из базы - напишите откуда, можно будет сделать еще проще.

**Добавлено пояснение**:
Как уже написал другой Александр в комментарии к вопросу:

> Строки сперва обрабатываются php, а потом уже сформированный запрос
>   отправляется в mysql

Поэтому у Вас и выдаётся ошибка. Фактически, Вы отправляли в базу вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
@status_:= status AS status_, 
Array[@status_] AS level
FROM users
```